# Weighing by missing observations

Tags: missing-data, weights

I have data where each row represents an observation and each column represents a variable. Variables are binary and has missing values.

I want to calculate a sum of the presence of these variables.

I thought of two ways:

- controlling for the number of NAs in each column

This would weigh those variables were more observations are available higher.

- controlling for number of NAs in each row

If there are a total 9 variables and Row 1 has 3 NA, the max amt  would be 6 and thus having 6 comorbidities could have a weighted sum of 6/9 or 0.66 repeating.

The point of all this is, that I have three groups and I want to know how many patients have at least 2 or more comorbidities. If I go ahead with the second approach, the condition would be fulfilled if the weighted sum > 2/9.

What do you think would be the best approach for this problem?